# Listening in on ANT+ device communication?

Tags: usb, hardware

I have TACX iGenius cycling trainer, which uses an ANT+ USB stick to control the resistance on the bicycle wheel. (You play a video in their software, and it matches the resistance on the wheel to your location in the video.)

TACX used to have the ability to record your own GPS tracks and videos and use them, but they have deprecated this option.

I want to understand the signals sent from the ANT+ USB stick to the trainer to control resistance, without interfering with the function of the trainer, so that I can try to write something to control it from my own videos without their software.

Is there a way to listen in on the data sent to and from the USB stick?   Or is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: If the software will work with the old USB1 stick, you will find it is just a cp210x USB->serial chip and a serial ANT chip inside.  Then it's a matter of sniffing a uart stream, which you can do with any logic analyzer or e.g. an FTDI cable.

Comment: You should also contact the Golden Cheetah mailing list.  GC has reverse-engineered support for a couple other Tacx trainers and might be willing to collaborate on your project.

Comment: *Then it's a matter of sniffing a uart stream, which you can do with any logic analyzer or e.g. an FTDI cable* ... if I understood that, it would help I think.  :)  Can you be more detailed, or can you tell me where to look for more beginner level information?  What I want to do is create a new RLV which will run in TTS 4 using the Sufferfest.com videos. I've created catalyst profiles for them, but trying to sync the video is a pain, since TACX doesn't allow you to minimize the TTS window.

Comment: I've seen and used RLVStudio to create other vids, but haven't been able to get them working in anyting higher than TTS 3.  And RLV Studio requires a .GPX file to create the route.  Even if you already have a PGMF or TTS file, you can't integrate it. At least that I've found...

Comment: What happens if it is an ANT+ 2 stick?  (It works with both, but the ANT2 stick allow multiple channels of throuhgput, and a much more stable connection.

Comment: Good call on the GC thing.  I'll have to get in touch with them.

Comment: @markrages, just realized I didn't tag my comments for you.

Comment: The easiest will be software only analyzer (@PeterJ's answer).  I believe the messages sent over USB are just ANT packets as described in the "message protocol and usage" document from www.thisisant.com.

Comment: Sorry I'm not much of a Windows guy, and I tend to think of hardware solutions first.

Answer (score 1):

Hardware USB analyzers tend to be fairly expensive but for a device already working a software analyzer should suffice. The following would be some good terms to search for:

- USB protocol analyzer
- USB bus analyzer
- USB bus sniffer

There is a question at StackOverflow with some answers that offer suggestions on some packages that are available if you're running Windows:

[What (software) usb sniffers are available for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315597/what-software-usb-sniffers-are-available-for-windows)